# Classical Mechanics Resources

Tags: classical-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I hope that my question doesn't violate the posting rules. I was wondering if any of you have any resources (websites, books, etc.) for classical mechanics. My first week of classical mechanics has shown me that this class is going to be extremely challenging. The textbook for the class is John R. Taylor's 'Classical Mechanics', which is alright, but I personally don't like the way the material is presented.

This class seems to focus on two things: Classical concepts and deriving the equation that will describe physical situations. A very basic example, taking the equation a=f/m and integrating twice to get an equation that describes the position of an object. If there are any resources for learning and applying that type of problem, then please let me know! Or, if you know of another place where my question would be more appropriate, then just point the way.

Anyway, any advice, resource, ANYTHING, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I will give you my usual advice (without violating the posting rules): go to the library and compare different books for their way of presenting the topic. No one book contains it all. No one author has all the answers. When you are learning physics you are doing more than just assimilating a well established set of standard derivations. You are building YOUR mental model of reality. It should include the standards but it needs to have more than that. If you can only see the things that everybody has seen in the standard textbooks, then you will never go past your peers.